# Create a table from JSON completely dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create entire table from a JSON array include dynamic `th`s, so a decoupled the head part to:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableDataTR from './TableTRView';
const TableView = ({ thds, tableData }) => {
    if (!thds) {
        return <table></table>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {thds.map((data, i) => <th key={i}>{data.th}</th>)}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <TableDataTR tableData={tableData}/>
            </table>

        </div>
    )
}
export default TableView;
```

And the table prints the head part, but I am having trouble printing my `tbody`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TableDataTR extends Component {
    render() {

       let rows = this.props.tableData.map((currElement, index) =>{
           return(
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>currElement[index]</td>
            </tr>
           ) 
       });


        return (
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        );
      }
}
export default TableDataTR;
```

Example data, table head

```
thds : [ { th: 'th1' },
        { th: 'th2' }]

tableData:[ { tdData1: 'somedata', tdData2: 'somedata2' },
            { tdData1: 'somedata', tdData2: 'somedata2' },]
```

The table head works fine, but the data inside `tbody` is not displaying at all.

The final goal is to get any 2 arrays and display the table accordingly.

Comment: Your data says `tabledata`, but you use props `tableData` with a capital `D`.

Comment: Sorry, a typo, editing....

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Close the question and create a sandbox instead?

Comment: That is exactly the opposite of dynamic, I want to make it as generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo again in your `<td>..</td>` part, missing `{}` for your expression. For the dynamic solution after first map you need to map your Objects as well.

```
<tr key={index}>
    <td>
        {
            Object.keys(currElement).map(key => currElement[key])
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Almost, it maps the entire object to one column.

Comment: Ah. But you got the idea :)

Comment: I think so, creating another component for rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the table data using key name as

```
let rows = this.props.tableData.map((currElement, index) => {
      return (
      <tr>
          { Object.keys(currElement).map((item) =>
          (
            <td>{currElement[item]}</td>
     )
       )}
      </tr>   
      )
    });
```

Comment: That is exactly the opposite of dynamic, I want to make it as generic.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas i have made the edit,Please do check whether it satisfies your need

Comment: Yes, this is the missing logic in my answer.